# Erro de conexão com o SQL Server em aplicações AspNetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework-6, asp-net-core

Estou enfrentando um problema "chatinho"... Qualquer projeto que inicio no Visual Studio ou VSCode e tento conectar ao banco SQL Server rodando via Docker, ocorre o erro abaixo:
[Erro de conexão SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Pao.png)

Mesmo apontando no arquivo de contexto, a conexão sempre tenta no usuário do print acima

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Pedido> Pedidos { get; set; }
public DbSet<PedidoItem> PedidoItems { get; set; }
public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost,1433;Database=DbPedidos;User Id=sa;Password=1q2w3e4r@#$;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True");
}
```

O que pode ser?

Comment: Esse print é de onde? stdout do container do SQL Server?

Comment: Brother, obrigado pela ajuda! A solução foi mudar o Integrated Security para False, está funcionando perfeitamente agora!
O print é do output da aplicação.